# What is going on in this ExecuteDataset method?

Tags: asp.net, sqlhelper

OK so I one page I find this line:

```
objDsCourse = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connstr").ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Course_NewReportGet_Get_Sav", objPAra)
```

And I copied it to another page to start modifying it to work there:

```
getData = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connstr").ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "Course_NewReportGet_Get_Sav", objPAra)
```

However on the new page it underlines .ConnectionStrings saying that Non-invocable member 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings' cannot be used like a method'... then why did it work in the other page??

EDIT: OK so I found in web.config what I think it is referencing because it says

```
<add name="ConnStr" connectionString="data source=..." />
```

Why would one page have access to this and the other not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any chance one page is using VB.NET, while the other is using C#?

Comment: YES! That is exactly true. I must be using it wrong then... brackets instead?

Comment: brackets instead of parenthesis seems to have fixed it, thanks for the tip *smacks forehead*

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Daniel.  In Visual Basic, both dictionary objects and methods are referenced by using parentheses. This can cause some confusion.

So in VB, `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connstr")` would point to the ConnectionString object with the key "connstr" in the dictionary.

In C#, dictionary objects are referenced by square brackets [] so `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connstr")` would literally mean "invoke the method ConnectionStrings of ConfigurationManager object using "connstr" as a parameter."

Long story short, check the <%@ Page %> declaration at the top to make sure both pages are the same language. ... or, on the page with the error, change the line to use the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"]` syntax.